# How can I compile Node global modules and objects in TypeScript with checkJs option set to true?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

If I add `"checkJs": true` to my `tsconfig.json` file, Node's global paths and objects are reported as "not found".

For instance, if I write:

```js
import path from "path";

const p = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js')
```

The TypeScript compiler is reporting:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module 'path'.
TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.
```

This is my `tsconfig.json` file's content:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/js/",
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "emitBOM": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

**What's required to successfully compile this code?**

TypeScript version is v3.3.3333.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found the answer, hidden in [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-types-):

You need to `npm install --save-dev @types/node`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your tsconfig file.

```js
{
   "moduleResolution": "node"
}
```

Comment: No change, I'm afraid.